# is changing voice technologies 2 ways?

Tags: voice

The software such as [MorphVOX](https://screamingbee.com/Product/MorphVOX.aspx) changes the voice to a man, woman, or etc.

But, i am wondering **is there any technology to roll back the audio file to what it was originally?**

For instance, if i have an audio file, which the voice is changed, am i able to reverse it to the original?

Comment: Mostly relies on are those effects effectively linear or not.

Answer (score 1):

You'd at least need to know what algorithm had been used originally. If you used the same software & in effect reversed that algorithm, you might get somewhere close.

If you start with 'just a voice' & you don't know what's been done to it, any attempt to reverse that would be total guesswork.